# Im on widows 7 school laptop and and when i open cmd.bat in c drive it closes when i press a key

Tags: windows-7

when I open command prompt bat file in shortcut in c drive  it opens but when I press a key it closes what do I do next? I need to access cmd so how do I use it without it closing?

Comment: What you describe is normal.  A .bat file normally closes when it reaches the end of the script unless your script specifically requests user input.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things at play here:

1)If you are creating a shortcut to a bat file - it is normal for it to close when it completes its instructions.

2)If your domain administrator has set a group policy on the machine to disallow access to cmd, then on some versions of windows it does load, tell you it has been disallowed and then closes on single key input.  Again this is normal and not something I am going to tell you how to circumvent.

Either way, it looks like its been locked down to disallow you access, so go speak to your school IT team if you have a genuine and legitimate reason for wanting to access the command prompt.